# How to handle both /url and /url/ redirects with htaccess?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, trailing-slash

I am rewriting all URLs and shorthand some of them:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(([^\.]+))\.pl [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.pl%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^test$ test-page.php [R=301,L]
```

so that
`example.pl/test` redirects to `example.pl/test-page.php`

but
`example.pl/test/` redirects to `example.pl/`

while it should:
`example.pl/test/` redirects to `example.pl/test-page.php`

How to handle both `/url` and `/url/` redirects?

I assume that it has to something with trailing slash.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 
RewriteRule ^test$ test-page.php [R=301,L]
```

Tested [here](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to make trailing slash optional using `/?$` regex. Try these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^.]+)\.pl [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1.pl%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^test/?$ test-page.php [NC,R=301,L]
```

Make sure to test this in a new browser to avoid 301 caching issues.

Comment: What I have more rewrites like that? While `/?$` works, I would be happy with global solution rather than per-rule

Comment: You can have any # of rewrites. Let me know what specific URLs you want to rewrite?

Comment: What do you mean by `All of requests`? Is this answer not working for you? You need to provide specifics for this answer isn't working so that I can suggest other ways.